# Do you have to pay for GNU GPL software that is "for sale"?

Tags: licensing

I've seen some software (a Joomla component, to be exact) for sale on a web site. The web site says it is licensed under the GNU GPL2. However it also says you need to pay for every site you use the software on (with bulk discounts).

I know it's perfectly acceptable to sell software under the GPL, however the [license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) implies that the source code must be distributed at no cost.

So is this a legitimate use of the GPL, or is it violating the license? Is it legal to download the software for free (say, from Bittorrent) and use it as I wish?

Comment: Why are we closing this? This IS programming related, as much as any other topic related the work surrounding programming. There are many famous, popular, and unclosed topics one could site to validate this topic.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if we understood why the vendor was not making the source available themselves.  Perhaps you can post a link to the web site in question?

Comment: I agree, this **should not** be closed. However, if it is closed, I'm pretty sure it will be reopened.

Comment: I think it should remain open because the answer isn't obvious.  Plenty of people - me included until just now - would assume GPL means that source has to be available to anyone who wants it.

Comment: There are close trigger happy people in this community whose behavior is difficult to understand.

Comment: @JeffP: Because it's a Joomla component, there are no binaries. It's all PHP/HTML/CSS/JS (and maybe some other acronyms). So they are making the source code available. If you're interested, the site is http://www.mosets.com/tree/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licencing, and not a specific programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: @durron597 should this be moved to Programmers.SE? Seems like it would be on topic there.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat questions about licensing _your own_ software are on-topic at Programmers.SE. This question would be off-topic there. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Snowman is correct. Also, Stack Exchange strongly discourages migrating very old questions for any reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a [FAQ from the GNU site](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney). I think it answers your question:

> **Does the GPL allow me to sell copies
>   of the program for money?**
>
> Yes, the GPL allows everyone to do this. The right to sell copies is part
>   of the definition of free software.
>   Except in one special situation, there
>   is no limit on what price you can
>   charge. (The one exception is the
>   required written offer to provide
>   source code that must accompany
>   binary-only release.)

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney

Further more:

> **If I distribute GPL'd software for a fee, am I required to also make it
>   available to the public without a
>   charge?**
>
> No. However, if someone pays your fee
>   and gets a copy, the GPL gives them
>   the freedom to release it to the
>   public, with or without a fee. For
>   example, someone could pay your fee,
>   and then put her copy on a web site
>   for the general public.

Comment: Also:  Does the GPL allow me to distribute copies under a nondisclosure agreement?

    No. The GPL says that anyone who receives a copy from you has the right to redistribute copies, modified or not. You are not allowed to distribute the work on any more restrictive basis.

Comment: So in this case, what keeps them in business? You can distribute the plug-in for free, but you must pay to license it for use on your Joomla website? If that's not it, I don't see the reason to buy multiple copies when the license says you can make copies of your single purchase.

Comment: Perhaps they sell services with the purchase? So, they'll provide expert, implementation specific support that would otherwise be unavailable from other possible distributions. I believe this is the idea of some Linux Distributions.

Answer (score 9):

For GPL software, the source code must be distributed with the binary version or upon request to anyone who legally obtains the binary version.

Ergo, if you didn't buy the product from them, they are under no obligation to give you the source code.

The obvious flip side to this is that anyone who DOES legitimately get the source code is free to redistribute it as they please.

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding distributing it on bittorrent would be redistribution which is permitted under the GPL without limitation (however Trademarks etc could still be violated!) This is how projects like [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) work - they remove the trademarks, rebuild and then redistribute - and this is perfectly legal.

The company themselves are under no obligation to release source code unless they distribute the software to you.

So your options are:

- **Get it from someone else** (who redistributes it under the GPL)
- **Purchase the product from the company** - they'll give you the source code

I would personally suggest the latter option because it supports companies that support the GPL!

Answer (score 0):

One question is whether the author wrote all the software or used any pre-existing GPLed software.  If the person on the web site owns the copyright completely, then the web site may impose any conditions, including those incompatible with the GPL.  Of course, releasing it under the GPL gives you some rights by itself.  In particular, you can't redistribute without the source code, but you can make copies and use them.

The above practice is generally considered unfriendly by Free and Open Source Software advocates.  Since it's not really honest to advertise GPLv2 and not deliver everything necessary, I'd advise being careful about the product.  People who deliberately misrepresent things in advertising are likely to be selling shoddy software.

If the software contains pre-existing GPLed components, and the author didn't come to other terms with the copyright holders, then the GPL applies in full.  The distributor has to provide source code (either with the executable or on request at nominal cost) and may not impose restrictions not allowed by the GPL.

There's also the possibility that the author released under GPLv2 without actually understanding the license.  This happens from time to time, and frequently the FSF will quietly work with companies on getting into compliance.

In either case, it's perfectly fine to sell the software.  If somebody else has the software including the source, they can redistribute freely, and it's perfectly legal for you to get it from them.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a very simple business trick that relies on the naivity of the purchaser. It is obvious that, if the component is GPL, you can get it from any other user (bittorrent, file sharing), redistribute it and even resell it (but keep it GPL).

It is also very obvious that, if there's no other source to find/get it from, if you purchase, there is absolutely no need to pay multiple times for it. You just need to buy it once, and re-use it on all of the websites that you wish.

Even if it has some source of protection, the source code is open, so you can easily remove that protection.

Just out of curiousity, can you please give the name/website of the Joomla! component?

Comment: The component is Mosets Tree, as I said in the comments on the question.